# Oracle : Not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a procedure that inserts a person to table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE wypisz
(ID1 NUMBER,
Imie1 VARCHAR2,
Nazwisko1 VARCHAR2,
Wiek1 NUMBER,
Stan_cywilny1 VARCHAR2,
Telefon1 VARCHAR2,
Pesel1 CHAR,
Id_adresu1 NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
      insert INTO Osoby(Id_osoby,Imie,Nazwisko,Wiek,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU) 
      VALUES (||Id1,||Imie1,||Nazwisko1,||Wiek1,||STAN_CYWILNY1,||TELEFON1,||PESEL1,||ID_ADRESU)
END;
```

When I call the function:

```
CALL WYPISZ(:ID_OSOBY, :IMIE, :NAZWISKO, :WIEK, :STAN_CYWILNY, :TELEFON, :PESEL, :ID_ADRESU)
```

I get the error:

```
SQL Error [6576] [65000]: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

Comment: Please check if procedure is valid or not. Is there any error in procedure?

Comment: Unfortunately - nothing.

Comment: You cannot get that procedure in database because you have a typo: no semicolon at the end of `INSERT`. Pleace, execute the entire code you have (with `CALL` statement) in SQL Plus (or as single SQL file with F5 in most IDE) and show us the output.

Comment: First make sure `wypisz` is in a valid state. The `||` symbols are one problem but we can't guess them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE wypisz(
  ID1           OSOBY.ID_OSOBY%TYPE,
  Imie1         OSOBY.IMIE%TYPE,
  Nazwisko1     OSOBY.NAZWISKO%TYPE,
  Wiek1         OSOBY.WIEK%TYPE,
  Stan_cywilny1 OSOBY.STAN_CYWILNY%TYPE,
  Telefon1      OSOBY.TELEFON%TYPE,
  Pesel1        OSOBY.PESEL%TYPE,
  Id_adresu1    OSOBY.ID_ADRESU%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  insert INTO Osoby(
    Id_osoby,Imie,Nazwisko,Wiek,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU
  ) VALUES (
    Id1,Imie1,Nazwisko1,Wiek1,STAN_CYWILNY1,TELEFON1,PESEL1,ID_ADRESU1
  );
END;
/
```

Which, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Osoby(
  Id_osoby     NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  Imie         VARCHAR2(50),
  Nazwisko     VARCHAR2(50),
  Wiek         NUMBER,
  STAN_CYWILNY VARCHAR2(20),
  TELEFON      VARCHAR2(12),
  PESEL        CHAR(1),
  ID_ADRESU    NUMBER
);
```

Then you can do:

```sql
BEGIN
  wypisz( 1, 'ABC', 'DEF', 2, 'GHI', '123456789012', 'J', 3 );
END;
/
```

And the table contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Osoby;
```

> ```
> ID_OSOBY | IMIE | NAZWISKO | WIEK | STAN_CYWILNY | TELEFON      | PESEL | ID_ADRESU
> -------: | :--- | :------- | ---: | :----------- | :----------- | :---- | --------:
>        1 | ABC  | DEF      |    2 | GHI          | 123456789012 | J     |         3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8c87f4ae51e39b3d65b552af4e93f5e)*

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use || operator.

```
insert INTO Osoby(Id_osoby,Imie,Nazwisko,Wiek,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU) 
      VALUES (Id1,Imie1,Nazwisko1,Wiek1,STAN_CYWILNY1,TELEFON1,PESEL1,ID_ADRESU1);
```

Also, you are missing ; at the end of insert statement.

Comment: Still same error - SQL Error [6576] [65000]: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name.

Comment: Please use proper names of the variable and see if procedure creation errors out or not. You need to fix the procedure before calling it. You can use `show error` command.

Comment: Okay, I added proper variable names and got same error. CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE wypisz
(a NUMBER,
b VARCHAR2,
c VARCHAR2,
d NUMBER,
e VARCHAR2,
f VARCHAR2,
g CHAR,
h NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
      insert INTO Osoby(ID_OSOBY ,IMIE ,NAZWISKO ,WIEK ,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU) 
      VALUES (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
END;

Comment: You are missing semicolon at the end of insert statement.

Comment: Added:            insert INTO Osoby(ID_OSOBY ,IMIE ,NAZWISKO ,WIEK ,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU)
      VALUES (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);

Answer (score 0):

you also have an invalid value in insert stmt -> ID_ADRESU and should be ID_ADRESU1
your proc is not compiling that's why you get your error when trying to call it;

`PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`
`PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here`

you can check what's the status of your proc by executing stmt below; you cannot call it if it has status invalid:

```
select t.object_name, t.status from user_objects t
where t.object_name = 'WYPISZ';
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE wypisz
(ID1 NUMBER,
Imie1 VARCHAR2,
Nazwisko1 VARCHAR2,
Wiek1 NUMBER,
Stan_cywilny1 VARCHAR2,
Telefon1 VARCHAR2,
Pesel1 CHAR,
Id_adresu1 NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
      insert INTO Osoby(Id_osoby,Imie,Nazwisko,Wiek,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU) 
      VALUES (Id1,Imie1,Nazwisko1,Wiek1,STAN_CYWILNY1,TELEFON1,PESEL1,ID_ADRESU1);
END;
```

Comment: I edited ID_ADRESU to ID_ADRESU1 and still same error.

Comment: add ; after your insert statement in your proc

Comment: Okay, added:  insert INTO Osoby(ID_OSOBY ,IMIE ,NAZWISKO ,WIEK ,STAN_CYWILNY,TELEFON,PESEL,ID_ADRESU)
      VALUES (Id1,Imie1,Nazwisko1,Wiek1,STAN_CYWILNY1,TELEFON1,PESEL1,ID_ADRESU1);